# ActionScript drawRoundRect rendering inconsistent corner radii

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to draw a shape with quite precise rounded corners, I'd settle for anything around 3px. Unfortunately Flash has other ideas, and is creating a rounded rectangle with four seemingly different radii. My code is below:

```
var sq:Shape = new Shape();
sq.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,1);
sq.graphics.drawRoundRect(20,20,20,20,4,4);
sq.graphics.endFill();
addChild(drop);
```

I removed the line as apparently fills render better, and changed to an even number radius as apparently that helps, but it's still the same. The code above gives me a square like so:

[image: Zoomed in view of sqaure]

The corners are noticeably different. If I were using a bigger radius it might not be so much of a problem, but because of the small radius of the corners the square just looks odd.

Have I missed the drawRoundRectEvenly function or am I asking too much here? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Darren

Comment: yep, rounded corners are a PITA in flash. with these small radii you can't hope to get better results. sorry :(

Comment: If u zoom this much, in phoshop also seems like this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting pixelHinting to true.

```
sq.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1.0, true);
```

Even if you're not using strokes, try it with an alpha 0 and see if it helps smooth things a bit. It will most likely still not be perfect, but it should snap to pixels a bit better and clean up dramatically.